# How to run a Fortran code more than 10^9 times in ftn95?

Tags: fortran

I need to run a Fortran code more than 10^9 times in ftn95. When I try to run my code more than 10^9 times it gives a error message "this loop will never be executed". In a book I read that if we declare a variable like `integer(kind=16)::k` then it will be able to run more than 10^9 times but in ftn95 its not working.

So if anyone know about this please tell me how to handle large integers in ftn95. Since I started to write code in fortran just before some days I don't know much about this language.

Comment: BTW, I believe that you should also learn other programming languages. [OCaml](http://caml.inria.fr/ocaml/) is very fun and is sometimes used for small numerical computations. If you want to code large numerical software running on supercomputers, consider also learning [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11). If you are interested in GPGPU computing, look into [OpenCL](http://www.khronos.org/opencl).. And [R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29) & [SciLab](http://www.scilab.org/) are also worth your interest

Comment: Also, Linux is probably a better environment (than Windows) to learn numerical programming

Comment: Actually my code is not very small this contains more than 300 lines, lot of arrays, so fortran is good for this type of work. And I had written my code in c++ but this did not gave true result so I have to work on fortran. I wasted my 2 months in finding error in c++ code but could not. Finally I decided to work on fortran.

Comment: You should have asked, after a few days of work, a question about your C++ issues on StackOverflow showing your code. And 300 lines is a small code (large code size would be ten millions lines). I am not sure that switching to Fortran would make your life easier (and Fortran has much less developers than C++). You need to improve your debugging skills.

Comment: Ok, after finishing this problem I will try to get error in my c++ code.

Answer (score 2):

Just use two nested loops. The outer loop would for example loop from `i=1` to `i=1000000` and the inner loop (inside the body of the outer loop) would loop from `j=1` to `j=10000`. Et voilà, a 10<sup>10</sup>-times running thing.

```
 DO i=1, 1000000
   DO j=1, 10000
     CALL something() 
   END DO
 END DO
```

The `CALL something()` would be done 10<sup>10</sup>-times

Notice that 10<sup>10</sup> is not representable as a 32 bits integer. You might try to use an 8 byte integer:

```
INTEGER (KIND=8) :: k
DO k=1, 10000000000_8
  CALL someotherthing(k)
END DO
```

The `_8` suffix on the `10000000000` tells that that constant is an 8 bytes (64 bits) integer.

<sup>BTW, I never coded in Fortran in my life (I much prefer Common Lisp, Ocaml, or C++11). But I did read a few books about it. So you have to check by yourself if my code is correct.</sup>

You might need to upgrade your compiler. Did you consider using a recent version (4.9 and soon 5.0) of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) which provides [gfortran](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/), and you might want to switch to some more recent standard (e.g. [Fortran 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran#Fortran_2008) at least).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I can't use two nested loops because let m=10^10 and I run code for i=1,m then in the last in code I have to again use this m if I will use two nested loops I will not able to use this m. And second is giving a error "error-217-INTEGER (KIND=3) constant out of range". Now what should I do?

Comment: The `KIND=` is the width in bytes of your numerical types (and should probably be some small power of two). Don't use `KIND=3` but `KIND=8`

Comment: I am not using kind=3. I am using kind=8 but when it gives error then kind=3 is used I don't know why ?

Comment: You should first search by yourself. After a few hours of work, if you are still stuck, consider asking on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) another question, with a *small source code sample* showing the issue you are struggling wih.

Comment: If you have a 64 bits processor (e.g. x86-64 or AMD64) like on most laptops and desktops, install a 64 bits Linux distribution.

Comment: @AtulKumarVerma: I never coded Fortran  by myself, but Basil is 100% right: try to get the second example working by yourself, replace 10000000000_8 by your "m" if you like, and when you cannot figure it out within an hour, post it as a question on stackoverflow.com.